Does (if so, why) aspect-ratio with one size set in % behave differently in firefox and chrome?
Consider the following situation: We have a flex container with two subcontainers - left and right - which should get both 50% of the containers width. This is done by setting flex-basis: 0 and flex-shrink and flex-grow to 1 on both.
Also, we have an inner component with a fixed height of 100px and an aspect ratio set. If this aspect ratio leads to a wider width of the inner component than the containers, then in chrome and firefox we see different results:
In chrome the container becomes wider (analogulously to setting an overly large width in px). In firefox it does not (as with setting the width to a high value in %).
Why is that? Does firefox resolve the other dimension in percent aswell and chrome does otherwise?
Example:


.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

.w-full {
  width: 100%;
}

.inner {
  background: green;
  height: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 100 / 1;
}

.flex-1 {
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-1" style="background: red">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-1" style="background: orange">
    Banana
  </div>
</div>




min-width: 0 also fixes the problem the same way overflow does: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/8620333
